# copy the contents of a variable in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, files

I want to know how I can put the contents of a variable in a text file.
This variable is a string that I want the code with the base64 command.But this command only works on files.
I wonder if there are other possibilities for this task

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing? `echo $var > file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a text file, you can use this:

```
base64 <<< "$var"
```

or

```
echo "$var" | base64
```

Example:

```
var="abcde"
base64 <<< "$var"
```

results

```
YWJjZGUK
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Here Strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). It is supported by `bash`, `zsh` and other common shells.

Example: The `grep` command only work with files but here we are passing a variable using Here Strings to be searched for pattern by `grep`.

```
$ str="this is a test line"
$ grep -o "test" <<< "$str"
test
```

As far as your command is concerned you can use:

```
$ base64 <<< "$str"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you want to base64 encode the content of a variable:

```
$ TEXT=test
$ ENCODED=$(echo "$TEXT" | base64)
$ echo "$ENCODED"
dGVzdAo=
```

Comment: `"$var"` and `${var}` are not the same. Choose the former to avoid word splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: correct, updated.